# Do you know how to emulate holding down a keystroke for any period of time, then releasing it later?

Tags: windows, delphi, key, sendinput

I'm trying to emulate pushing the keyboard V key down while using BASS library to automate Voice Activation push to talk.  I've got the BASS library working, just can't get the keyboard to simulate holding down a Key for any length of time!

Edit:
<strike>I am trying to get another application ('TeamSpeak 3') to recognize my Key Press & hold as a hardware based Key Press & Hold rather than a software based Key Press & Hold.  To help simulate a Push to Talk via my application.  I will openly have the source code for anyone that wants it, but I will not be publishing my application for any reason.  It's for my personal use and It's out of curiosity if it would work?  I understand that any kind of abuse of this kind of app I take as my own personal responsibility.</strike>

Edit2: I have done extensive research.  I figure I'm going to have to either use my old Android handheld or a Raspberry Pi.  I have a Raspberry Pi Zero, so I am going to see if I can create it as a hardware keyboard.  I'll write a program in Delphi to interface it (I have Delphi 10.4.1 Enterprise and hope it will work with Raspberry Pi's linux version.)  I have a vmware Debian and Ubuntu os on my computer that I could pre-compile it with?  Anyhow the article is here: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/

I'm going to go ahead an allow the answer below, because it basically does what my previous request says.  To go further than my request requires a lot of work.  I'll give an update if I can get it working properly.

(Delphi 10.4.1 / Target Windows 32-bit)

Here's my current source code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.MPlayer, System.UITypes, BASS,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    Timer2: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function RecordingCallback(h:HRECORD; b:Pointer; l,u: DWord): boolean; stdcall;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  rchan:   HRECORD; // recording channel
  level2: dword;
  LoudEnough: boolean = FALSE;
  threshold: DWORD = 500; // trigger level
  MicON_Timer, Counter1: Cardinal;
  MicON_Bool : Boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

(* This function called while recording audio *)
function TForm1.RecordingCallback(h:HRECORD; b:Pointer; l,u: DWord): boolean; stdcall;
 //var level:dword;
 begin
  level2:=BASS_ChannelGetLevel(h);
  LoudEnough := (LoWord(level2) >= threshold) or (HiWord(level2) >= threshold);
  //Memo1.Lines.add('Loword ' + IntToStr(LoWord(level))+' - HiWord '+IntToStr(HiWord(level)));
  Result := True;
 end;

// START BUTTON
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {
  if BASS_RecordSetDevice(0) = false then
  begin
    memo1.Lines.Add('BASS_RecordSetDevice ERROR = '+ BASS_ErrorGetCode().ToString);
  end;}

  Counter1 := 0;
  MicON_Timer := 0;

  Timer1.Enabled := true;
  ComboBox1Change(Self);
  rchan := BASS_RecordStart(44100, 1, 0, @TForm1.RecordingCallback, nil);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
  rchan := BASS_RecordStart(44100, 1, BASS_RECORD_PAUSE, @TForm1.RecordingCallback, nil);
    //BASS_Free();
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
    i: Integer;
  r: Boolean;
begin
    // enable the selected input
    r := True;
    i := 0;
    // first disable all inputs, then...
    while r do
    begin
        r := BASS_RecordSetInput(i, BASS_INPUT_OFF, -1);
        Inc(i);
    end;
    // ...enable the selected.
    BASS_RecordSetInput(ComboBox1.ItemIndex, BASS_INPUT_ON, -1);
    //UpdateInputInfo;  // update info
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  BASS_RecordFree;
  BASS_Free();
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  dName: PAnsiChar;
  level: Single;
  flags: dWord;
  deviceInfo: BASS_DEVICEINFO;
  info: BASS_INFO;
begin
    // check the correct BASS was loaded
    if (HIWORD(BASS_GetVersion) <> BASSVERSION) then
    begin
        MessageBox(0,'An incorrect version of BASS.DLL was loaded', nil,MB_ICONERROR);
        Halt;
    end;
    if (not BASS_RecordInit(-1)) or (not BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, Handle, nil)) then
    begin
        BASS_RecordFree;
        BASS_Free();
        MessageDlg('Cannot start default recording device!', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
        Halt;
    end;
    i := 0;
//  dName := BASS_RecordGetInputName(i);
  //dName := (BASS_RecordGetDeviceInfo(i,deviceInfo));
    while (BASS_RecordGetDeviceInfo(i,deviceInfo)) do
    begin
    //BASS_GetInfo(info);
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(String(deviceInfo.name));
        // is this one currently "on"?
    //flags := BASS_RecordGetInput(i, level);
    //if (flags and BASS_INPUT_TYPE_MASK) = BASS_INPUT_TYPE_MIC then
        if (BASS_RecordGetInput(i, level) and BASS_INPUT_OFF) = 0 then
            ComboBox1.ItemIndex := i;
        Inc(i);
        //dName := BASS_RecordGetInputName(i);
    end;
    ComboBox1Change(Self);  // display info
end;


procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  eu: array [0..1] of TInput;
  //S: String;
begin
  //S:='v';
  level2:=BASS_ChannelGetLevel(rchan);
  inc(Counter1);
  LoudEnough := (LoWord(level2) >= threshold) or (HiWord(level2) >= threshold);

  if (LoudEnough = true) then
  begin
    inc(MicON_Timer);

    if (MicON_Bool = false) then
    begin
      MicON_Bool := true;

      //keybd_event(ord('v'), MapVirtualKey(ord('v'), 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
      //keybd_event(ord('v'), MapVirtualKey(ord('v'), 0), 0, 0);

      ZeroMemory(@eu,sizeof(eu));
      eu[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
      eu[0].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
      eu[0].ki.wVk := 0;
      eu[0].ki.wScan   := ord('v');
      eu[0].ki.Time := 0;
      SendInput(1,eu[0],sizeof(TInput));

      Memo1.Lines.add('Push to Talk ON');

      Timer2.Enabled := true;
    end;
  end;

  //if LoudEnough then Memo1.Lines.add('Push to Talk ON')
    //else Memo1.Lines.add('Push to Talk OFF');
  //Memo1.Lines.add('Loword ' + LoWord(level2).ToString +' - HiWord '+ HiWord(level2).ToString + ' - AVG: ' + MicON_Timer.ToString);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  eu: array [0..1] of TInput;
begin
  dec(MicON_Timer);
  if MicON_Timer <= 0 then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.add('Push to Talk OFF');

    //keybd_event(ord('v'), MapVirtualKey(ord('v'), 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    ZeroMemory(@eu,sizeof(eu));
    eu[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    eu[0].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_UNICODE or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    eu[0].ki.wVk := 0;
    eu[0].ki.wScan   := ord('v');
    eu[0].ki.Time := 0;
    SendInput(1,eu[0],sizeof(TInput));

    MicON_Bool := false;
    Counter1 := 0;
    MicON_Timer := 0;

    Timer2.Enabled := false;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, shouldn't timer1 be disabled at some point?

Comment: I hope I don't have to go as far as creating a virtual serial port, then simulating keyboard information through that Virtual serial port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I designed a simple example where when the user click the mouse on a TButton, it simulate a keystroke every 250mS until the user release the mouse button.

The OnMouseButtonDown starts a 250mS timer, the OnMouseButtonUp stop the timer. The OnTimer send the keyboard event. The timer is also stopped when the mouse leave the form.

The .PAS file:

```
unit KbdEmulDemoMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
        TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Button1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
        TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm1.Button1MouseDown(
    Sender : TObject;
    Button : TMouseButton;
    Shift  : TShiftState;
    X, Y   : Integer);
begin
    // Set focus on Memo1 so that it will receive keyboard input
    Memo1.SetFocus;
    // Start the timer sending keyboard event
    Timer1.Interval := 250;
    Timer1.Enabled  := TRUE;
    // Call OnTimer immediately to key first key event right now
    Timer1.OnTimer(nil);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseUp(
    Sender : TObject;
    Button : TMouseButton;
    Shift  : TShiftState;
    X, Y   : Integer);
begin
    // Stop timer, this will stop key event
    Timer1.Enabled := FALSE;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
    // Stop timer, this will stop key event
    Timer1.Enabled := FALSE;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
    Eu: array [0..1] of TInput;
begin
    ZeroMemory(@Eu, SizeOf(Eu));
    Eu[0].Itype      := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Eu[0].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    Eu[0].ki.wVk     := 0;
    Eu[0].ki.wScan   := Ord('v');
    Eu[0].ki.Time    := 0;
    SendInput(1, Eu[0], Sizeof(TInput));
end;

end.
```

And the DFM file:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 24
    Top = 28
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnMouseDown = Button1MouseDown
    OnMouseLeave = Button1MouseLeave
    OnMouseUp = Button1MouseUp
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 20
    Top = 76
    Width = 605
    Height = 213
    Lines.Strings = (
      'Memo1')
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object Timer1: TTimer
    OnTimer = Timer1Timer
    Left = 168
    Top = 24
  end
end
```

Comment: Will this work if the target app uses GetAsyncKeyState?

Comment: It works on Notepad, but doesn't want to work against an app that is "targeting real hardware"?  I'm not sure how to use GetAsyncKeyState?  I'll look that up though and see if I can find examples.  In Stack Overflow, there isn't any information on Delphi SetAsyncKeyState for which I believe I barely looked at a while back.  In all honesty I'm trying to target TeamSpeak 3 app which can force players to use Push to Talk and I want to use Voice Activity Detection...for which I was able to do using BASS, but the push to talk alludes me via my app pressing the button!

Comment: You should better explain what you intend to do. Maybe "holding down a keystroke" is not what you really need. I understood that you have an application "TeamSpeak 3" that you want to cheat by having another application pushing on the keyboard instead of a physical person actually pushing and holding a key. Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION to put all information there instead of in comments.

Comment: I've edited the question, chosen the answer that works for my question because it does work for my question if used on notepad. I decided I'm going to have to use my Delphi 10.4.1 Enterprise to write a linux program for Raspberry Pi and hope it works.  I'll use my Raspberry Pi Zero as a hardware keyboard and this should solve the issue I'm having.  I know Delphi 10.4.1 Enterprise isn't currently approved for Raspberry Pi, so I'll first compile it on Ubuntu first and carry it over?  Or I may put in a request ticket to Embarcadero to maybe add Raspberry Pi support.

Comment: About Delphi for RPi: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13370

Comment: Maybe an Arduino would be a hardware solution to your problem. Cheaper than RPI and already done. See: https://maker.pro/arduino/projects/how-to-turn-an-arduino-into-a-keystroke-automation-tool

Answer (score 0):

> What about SendKeys.Send ?

Supposing the target application has no DCOM equivalent, as SendKeys.Send targets the active application, so if the focus is changed by another application you do not obtain the desired results.